# Kurento - Sailsjs communication: Unexpected token

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js, kurento, skipper

I have some troubles while connecting a Socket.io instance from Sailsjs and Kurento (locally, on a Docker instance).

When I try to connect to Kurento with this code (on a Sailsjs service):

```
var kurento = require('kurento-client');
var ws_uri = 'ws://localhost:8812/kurento';
kurento(ws_uri, function(error, _kurentoClient) {
    // Logic here
});
```

I got this error on the console (the callback is never called):

```
[SyntaxError: Unexpected token u001b[90m{"id":0,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result"{"value":"pong"}}\n\u001b[39m'
[SyntaxError: Unexpected token u001b[90m{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"hierarchy":["kurento.MediaObject"],"qualifiedType":"kurento.ServerManager","sessionId":"0296ed75-bba7-4728-a4d8-25bb5715f442","type":"ServerManager"}}\n\u001b[39m'
```

I understand that there is a problem while parsing the response from the Kurento server (probably an encoding problem), but I can't figure out where this response is parsed (body-parser of Sails?).

When I run the tutorial examples, it runs normally, but not with Sails.

Anyone have faced the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is caused by JSON color code. You can fix "unpack" function in JSONrpc.js (library) by removing color code - delete color code from string. That's all.